# I would like to activate a term in my differential equation when a certain condition has been met for the first time

Tags: python, math, physics

In my code I am solving a differential equation using the following code:

```
m_p=1
l = 10**(-10)
G = 0.8*10**(-5)
m=10e-05*m_p

c1 = (4*np.pi)/(m_p**2)
c2 = (8*np.pi)/(3*(m_p**2))
c3 = (4*np.pi)/(3*(m_p**2))

def da_dt2(a, p): #a[0] = phi, a[1] = dphi/dN
    return [a[1],(c1*a[1]**3)-(3+(G*((c2*((0.5*m**2*a[0]**2)+(l*a[0]**4)))**(-0.5))*(1-(c3*a[1]**2))**(0.5)))*a[1]-(((m**2)*a[0]+4*l*(a[0]**3))/((0.5*(m**2)*(a[0]**2))+(l*(a[0]**4))))*c2**(-1)*(1-c3*a[1]**2)]

a0=[3,0] #initial conditions for phi and dphi/dN? #going towards zero form a positive value
a=0 #initial value of N
b=56 #final value of N

N=np.arange(a,b,0.001) #list of N values to plot against
s=odeint(da_dt2, a0, N) #solves ode and returns dp/dN and p
```

The general solving works. However, I want to effectively permanently "turn-on" the term beginning with G in the da_dt2 function once a certain condition has been met for the first time. I'm not sure if this is possible and I would appreciate if anyone could give any help.

I think the main problem is that the graph I am plotting once the differential equation has been solved exhibits oscillatory behaviour around a zero value. This means that I can't use If statements as the condition of the variable phi or a[0] reaching zero occurs many times due to the oscillatory behaviour.

Comment: Not sure about the physics on this equation.  You're saying that your system becomes something else after a certain condition is met.  The state at that time becomes the initial condition for the new equation with the additional term.  Can the term drop out again if the system state falls below that triggering value?  Could be a tough system to solve.  You have to expect some transient behavior caused by the step change.

Comment: The term is meant to stay activated after the certain condition is met once, and then permanently stay activated, if that makes sense.

Comment: Got it, thank you.  Step changes are a shock to any system.  Maybe you could transition the effect in using a sigmoid weighting function and gradually decrease the transition time.